# JPEG library reports unrecoverable error

Tags: php

I am using image which i converted from pdf. now my this function showing error as

```
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: in /home/cabees/testing.cabees.com/insert.php on line 88


imagecreatefromjpeg($file_path);
```

How can I make this is actual image file.

Comment: I did seen this, Not working

Answer (score -1):

The `file` command (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) is useful for making sure that the file is indeed of the type that you expect.

If you have this utility available, compare the output of this command on your file to a file that you know for sure that it is of the jpeg format.

Comment: file is in correct proper format, i want to make better